# Template matching with multiple images with same template

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, template-matching

Can anyone help me with template matching? As per my guess, Computer vision works with the Pattern reading, so for e.g. If my template(template image) contains "Invoice Number" and my input file_1(Image 1) contains "Invoice number" then it is getting matched, but my input file_2(Image 2) contains "**Invoice number**" then it is not able to match. Is there any solution available to match the template like this?

Comment: Please show few examples so that we understand better

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE TEMPLATE FILE [Template Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH0oJ.jpg). THIS IS THE INPUT FILE 1 [Input File 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iuiG.jpg), & THIS ONE IS THE INPUT FILE 2 [Input File 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2gMX.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post an answer to add more detail. Edit your original answer. Please read the Help section on how to ask a good question.